# Requesting user input while reading file line by line

Tags: bash, shell-script, control-flow, user-input

For class I need to write a Bash script that will take the output from `ispell` and when I try and request user input inside the while loop it just saves the next line of the file as the user input.

How could I go about requesting user input in the while loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Returns the misspelled words
#ispell -l < file

#define vars
ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE="output.tmp";
INPUT_FILE=$1


ispell -l < $INPUT_FILE > $ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE;

#echo a new line for give space between command
#and the output generated
echo "";

while read line;
do
   echo "'$line' is misspelled. Press "Enter" to keep";
   read -p "this spelling, or type a correction here: " USER_INPUT;

   if [ $USER_INPUT != "" ]
   then
      echo "INPUT: $USER_INPUT";
   fi


   echo ""; #echo a new line
done < $ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE;

rm $ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that in your `while`. You need to use another [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

Try the following version :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Returns the misspelled words
#ispell -l < file

#define vars
ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE="output.tmp";
INPUT_FILE=$1


ispell -l < $INPUT_FILE > $ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE;

#echo a new line for give space between command
#and the output generated
echo "";

while read -r -u9 line;
do
   echo "'$line' is misspelled. Press "Enter" to keep";
   read -p "this spelling, or type a correction here: " USER_INPUT;

   if [ "$USER_INPUT" != "" ]
   then
      echo "INPUT: $USER_INPUT";
   fi


   echo ""; #echo a new line
done 9< $ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE;

rm "$ISPELL_OUTPUT_FILE"
```

See [How to keep other commands from "eating" the input](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

**NOTES**

- *USE MORE QUOTES!* They are vital.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
- `bash` is not `C` or `Perl`, no need to put `;` on each end lines

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<> /dev/stdin

ispell -l < $1 | while read line
do
    echo "'$line' is misspelled. Press 'Enter' to keep"
    read -u 3 -p "this spelling, or type a correction here: " USER_INPUT

    [ "$USER_INPUT" != "" ] && echo "INPUT: $USER_INPUT"
done
```